# trying to depunctuate getting the error "TypeError: invalid File: []"

Tags: python, string, token, punctuation

I'm trying to clear some tokens of the following punctuation by starting with an empty array then adding cleaned tokens to that array.

```
def main():
    tokens = readTokens("words.txt")
    depunctuatuate = depunctuateToken(tokens)

def readTokens(fileName):
    s = Scanner(fileName)
    items = []
    token = s.readstring()
    while (token != ""):
        items.append(token)
        token = s.readstring()
    print(items)
    s.close()
    return items

def depunctuateToken(string):
    result = []
    s = Scanner(string)
    token = s.readstring()
    punct = [",",".","?",":","'","-"]
    for i in range(0,len(string),1):
        if(not(string[i] in punct)):
            result += [string[i]]
    return result
```

Comment: I think `Scanner` needs `string`  to be  a filename.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: @AShelly or a file object.

Comment: This code seems to work. As @aIKid and @AShelly said, you need to look at ``Scanner``.

Comment: The readTokens pulls a file and reads it then the depunctuateToken is supposed to clean the token of punctuation

Comment: Even with it using the tokens gotten from a file it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `Scanner` in the `depunctuateToken` function.

You are passing it an array of strings,  Just iterate through them and do your `punct` filtering on each one.  You probably also want to modify your return statement,  right now it looks like it will return the first item only.